# Uniswap addLiquidity Error: "revert TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED"

Tags: solidity, remix, ganache, uniswap, liquidity-provider

I'm having issues with the addLiquidity() call failing due to what likely seems to be an approval issue and producing the following error code:

Internal JSON-RPC error. { "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED"

I'm calling:

```
(pylonSent, wethSent, lpTotalReward) = UNIROUTER.addLiquidity(address(token1), address(WETH), vals_[0].token1Amount, vals_[0].wethUser, vals_[0].token1Needed, vals_[0].wethNeeded, tokenvault, type(uint).max);
```

Where vals_[0].token1Amount, vals_[0].wethUser, vals_[0].token1Needed, vals_[0].wethNeeded are uint256.

vals_[0].token1Needed, vals_[0].wethNeeded were calculated using getAmountOut() and all of these values seem to be correct proportions (i.e. sufficient amounts so as not to violate _addLiquidity() in uniswap).

I've approved everything in the constructor:

```
WETH.approve(address(UNIROUTER), type(uint).max);

WETH.approve(address(token2), type(uint).max);

token1.approve(address(UNIROUTER), type(uint).max);

token1.approve(address(token2), type(uint).max);

token2.approve(address(UNIROUTER), type(uint).max);

token2.approve(address(this), type(uint).max);
```

where UNIROUTER = UniswapRouter(0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D);

&

Where token1 is the token I'm trying to combine with WETH to make token2...but it seems like something still can't transfer correctly or might need approval.

Any ideas on how to fix this or what might be causing the error?

I'm using remix and metamask connected to a local host that is running a ganache fork of main net.

Reference Uniswap code:

```
    // **** ADD LIQUIDITY ****
    function _addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint amountADesired,
        uint amountBDesired,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin
    ) internal virtual returns (uint amountA, uint amountB) {
        // create the pair if it doesn't exist yet
        if (IUniswapV2Factory(factory).getPair(tokenA, tokenB) == address(0)) {
            IUniswapV2Factory(factory).createPair(tokenA, tokenB);
        }
        (uint reserveA, uint reserveB) = UniswapV2Library.getReserves(factory, tokenA, tokenB);
        if (reserveA == 0 && reserveB == 0) {
            (amountA, amountB) = (amountADesired, amountBDesired);
        } else {
            uint amountBOptimal = UniswapV2Library.quote(amountADesired, reserveA, reserveB);
            if (amountBOptimal <= amountBDesired) {
                require(amountBOptimal >= amountBMin, 'UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_B_AMOUNT');
                (amountA, amountB) = (amountADesired, amountBOptimal);
            } else {
                uint amountAOptimal = UniswapV2Library.quote(amountBDesired, reserveB, reserveA);
                assert(amountAOptimal <= amountADesired);
                require(amountAOptimal >= amountAMin, 'UniswapV2Router: INSUFFICIENT_A_AMOUNT');
                (amountA, amountB) = (amountAOptimal, amountBDesired);
            }
        }
    }
    function addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint amountADesired,
        uint amountBDesired,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external virtual override ensure(deadline) returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity) {
        (amountA, amountB) = _addLiquidity(tokenA, tokenB, amountADesired, amountBDesired, amountAMin, amountBMin);
        address pair = UniswapV2Library.pairFor(factory, tokenA, tokenB);
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(tokenA, msg.sender, pair, amountA);
        TransferHelper.safeTransferFrom(tokenB, msg.sender, pair, amountB);
        liquidity = IUniswapV2Pair(pair).mint(to);
    }
    
    
// helper methods for interacting with ERC20 tokens and sending ETH that do not consistently return true/false
library TransferHelper {
    function safeApprove(address token, address to, uint value) internal {
        // bytes4(keccak256(bytes('approve(address,uint256)')));
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = token.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(0x095ea7b3, to, value));
        require(success && (data.length == 0 || abi.decode(data, (bool))), 'TransferHelper: APPROVE_FAILED');
    }

    function safeTransfer(address token, address to, uint value) internal {
        // bytes4(keccak256(bytes('transfer(address,uint256)')));
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = token.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(0xa9059cbb, to, value));
        require(success && (data.length == 0 || abi.decode(data, (bool))), 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FAILED');
    }

    function safeTransferFrom(address token, address from, address to, uint value) internal {
        // bytes4(keccak256(bytes('transferFrom(address,address,uint256)')));
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = token.call(abi.encodeWithSelector(0x23b872dd, from, to, value));
        require(success && (data.length == 0 || abi.decode(data, (bool))), 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED');
    }

    function safeTransferETH(address to, uint value) internal {
        (bool success,) = to.call{value:value}(new bytes(0));
        require(success, 'TransferHelper: ETH_TRANSFER_FAILED');
    }
}
```